# SSO Login, can we remove the Facebook color in the button?

Tags: login, facebook

I've been working on a login flow where we are allowing users to sign up or login with Facebook. The devs in my team told me that we need to keep the Facebook button with the colors :

[image: Facebook button]

However, we also have Linkedin and Google... So you can imagine how this looks like a rainbow.

Do you know if we can just remove those colors and using button with a white background instead? Do you have any official sources about this? For example, I know that Canva is doing that way :

[image: Canva login]

Thank you guys ! :)

Comment: What does Facebook say about the usage of their trademark? They probably have guidelines for the usage.

Comment: Please refer to my answer to [SSO Login, can we remove the Linkedin color in the button?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/135957/sso-login-can-we-remove-the-linkedin-color-in-the-button/136065#136065)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These companies each have their own guidelines for how you are legally allowed to use their trademarks.

[Facebook's developer guidelines](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/userexperience#buttondesign) instruct the developer to refer to the "f" logo brand guidelines when designing an SSO button.

[Facebook's trademark guidelines regarding usage of the "f" logo state](https://en.facebookbrand.com/facebookapp/):

> **Use the "f" Logo**
> Only use the "f" Logo to promote your presence on Facebook. Don't use the Facebook wordmark, which is the corporate identity that refers to Facebook Inc.
>
> **Maintain shape, color and proportions**
> To ensure accurate and consistent use, never alter, rotate, embellish or attempt to recreate Facebook brand assets. The downloads available here are the only approved assets to represent the Facebook brand.
> [image: Facebook "f" logo Do's and Don'ts]

So yes, you are allowed to remove the background color, provided the "f" logo still has the trademark blue. The trademark guidelines contain downloadable assets that are the only officially approved logos.