# SSO Login, can we remove the Linkedin color in the button?

Tags: buttons, login

I've been working on a login flow where we are allowing users to sign up or login with Linkedin. The devs in my team told me that we need to keep the Linkedin button with the colors :
[image]

However, we also have Facebook and Google... So you can imagine how this looks like a rainbow.

Do you know if we can just remove those colors and using button with a white background instead? Do you have any official sources about this? For example, I know that Canva is doing that way :
[image]

I can't find any clear information for guideline on Linkedin
Thank you guys !

Comment: Are you going to ask this for every possible social media SSO? https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/135812/sso-login-can-we-remove-the-facebook-color-in-the-button

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Yeah sure, we can find some information about logo but not about the specific SSO button

Answer (score 0):

i think it's fine to change the button style as long as you keep the shape of logo.

> can't find any clear information for guideline on Linkedin

Well, i just typed "linked in button guideline" on google and it shows in the first row:
https://brand.linkedin.com/downloads

Answer (score 0):

### Yes! You Can Use a Custom Button!

You can have any button or link on your site point to the LinkedIn OAuth authorization page where the member signs in and authorizes your application. Simply link to https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization with url parameters as defined in the [LinkedIn OAuth Developer Documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authorization-code-flow?context=linkedin/context#step-2-request-an-authorization-code).

For example:

[image]

This login page is available [here](https://auth0.com/auth/login). Examining the page shows that the LinkedIn button points directly to the LinkedIn OAuth URL as described above.

### Likely Origin of Initial Thinking

Your development team is likely using the [LinkedIn Javascript SDK](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/js-sdk/tutorials/tutorial). The SDK provides a function to invoke the authentication process. When added to the document body:

```
<script type="IN/Login"></script>
```

renders as:

[image]

While there are multiple methods of swapping the image once it's injected into the page, it's likely your developers wish to keep your application simple and straightforward - unfortunately in this case, it'd be at the expense of user experience.